# Unix script Excel report generation

Tags: excel, shell, scripting

I am creating an Excel file through shell script. The data should be in 4 columns,
but the output data came in one column.

Comment: Post some code. you should mention in your script which column in excel sheet will hold what data

Answer (score 1):

Create a comma-separated values file.
Perhaps, depending on your delimiters:

```
some process creates colon-separated data | while IFS=: read v1 v2 v3 v4; do
    printf "\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\"\n" \
        "$(sed 's/"/""/g' <<< "$v1")" \
        "$(sed 's/"/""/g' <<< "$v2")" \
        "$(sed 's/"/""/g' <<< "$v3")" \
        "$(sed 's/"/""/g' <<< "$v4")" \
    >> my_data.csv
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding new line at the end of each statement.